# Why is Chrome version 29 disproportionately popular?

Tags: google-chrome, browser

CanIUse's [browser stats table](http://caniuse.com/usage-table) shows Chrome version 29 having 0.68% of the browser market, far more than for every other version of a similar age. Versions 28 and 30 for example both have 0.03%, making version 29 almost **23x more popular**. On their stats it's actually more popular than every other version of Chrome up to 48 (January's release), despite now being almost 3 years old.

For comparison, 0.68% usage means **this outdated Chrome release is more popular than the current and previous versions of Opera, the penultimate version of Safari on iOS, and IE 9 or 10.**

A quick look at other sources like [Clicky](https://clicky.com/marketshare/global/web-browsers/google-chrome/) (which includes only version stats for recent Chrome, and Chrome v29), and [W3Counter](https://www.w3counter.com/globalstats.php) (which actually puts it up at 2%) seems to suggest this isn't just a local discrepancy.

I can't seem to find anything special about it though, either from the Google release notes or in [Wikipedia's release details](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome_release_history).

Where is this coming from? Why are so many more people using this specific version of Chrome? What on earth is going on?

Comment: This could be because of an auto update bug.

Comment: @SashaKoss Could be, but there's no mention of that on v30's release (http://googlechromereleases.blogspot.com.es/2013/10/stable-channel-update.html) or anywhere else I can see.

Comment: An another assumption: it could be a some anonymizer using a fake user agent string.

Answer (score 6):

Looks like Chrome 29 was the first version of Chrome on Android. I suppose there are still a lot of phones out there that haven't upgraded.

Answer (score 1):

On Apple iPad it was the last version supported on the original iPad, i.e. iOS 5.1.1.

I only stumbled across then when debugging some software running on a fleet of original iPads. Some corporates are loathe to throw out tablets that still work fine.